# Questions about a few terminologies in "Knots and Links" by Rolfsen

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

In *"Knots and Links"* by Rolfsen, he mentioned words like *"the collar of a boundary", "bicollared boundary", "a bicollar on the boundary". I just wonder what the definition of "collar" is. Also, what a flat ball is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *collar* is a small product neighbourhood of the boundary.

That is: Suppose that $M$ is a compact manifold. Let $\partial M$ be its boundary.  A *collar* of $\partial M$ in $M$ is a submanifold $N \subset M$ homeomorphic to $\partial M \times [0, 1]$ so that $\partial M$ is the zeroth slice.

As for a flat ball, could you give an example of usage?

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you also explain what the zeroth slice is? As for the flat ball, in the basic unknotting theorem, it says "A knot K^k in S^n (k<n) is equivalent to the trivial knot if and only if K is the boundary of a flat (k+1)-ball in S^n."

Comment: that should be short for "topologically locally flat" which would mean locally a neighborhood of the k+1 ball is homeomorphic to R^(k+1) + R^(n-k-1) (i.e. it looks topologically like it has a regular neighborhood)

Comment: Zeroth slice = boundary cross zero.  And I agree with @GageMartin's definition of "flat" as "topologically locally flat".